# Back button warning keycharmap

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android project and noticed an odd warning in my LogCat that occurs (almost) every time I hit the back button.

```
W/KeyCharacterMap(9001): Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap(9001): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qt602240key.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='qt602240key'
W/KeyCharacterMap(9001): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

There are two things that make this really weird.

1) If I go back and forth between two Activities, this only occurs the first consecutive time I hit the back button.  For instance, if I start on Activity A, go to Activity B, and hit back then the error appears.  But, if I go to Activity B and hit back again it does not appear.  Weirder still, if I then go to Activity C, hit back (the error appears as expected), then go to Activity B and back again, then the error starts appearing again.  It's only consecutive times between two Activities that it fails to appear.

2) This seems to happen BEFORE the back button press is resolved.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Here to implements for your code.
        Log.d("Sophie", "KEYCODE_BACK");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    Log.d("Sophie", "on back pressed");
}
```

yields the log:

```
01-07 13:13:38.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(9001): Can't open keycharmap file
01-07 13:13:38.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(9001): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qt602240key.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='qt602240key'
01-07 13:13:38.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(9001): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-07 13:13:38.020: D/Sophie(9001): KEYCODE_BACK
01-07 13:13:38.090: D/Sophie(9001): on back pressed
```

It's mildly concerning, but mostly just confusing.
Does anyone have the faintest idea as to what's going on?

Edit for more info:

The warning appears on other physical buttons as well (but not Home).  I've seen it on search, settings, and volume buttons.  However, the warning that came with the volume buttons used a different devname than the ones for the other three.